# How do I change the frame rate at which quicktime records movies?

Tags: video, mac-app-store

I'm trying to record a video of my screen using quicktime such that I can submit it to the app store as part of my product.  The app store keeps telling me that my video frame rate is too high.

Is there a setting I can change to adjust the frame rate?  How else can I record a video of my app that I can share on the store?